# Issued In Armies

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions, usage

I have a question about the usage of the preposition "in" in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ushanka#Current_use):

> Identified with Soviet rule and *issued* ***in*** *all Warsaw Pact armies*, the ushanka has become a part of the winter uniform for military and police forces in Canada, the United States, and other Western countries with a cold winter.

The use of "*in*" in "*issued* ***in*** *all Warsaw Pact armies*" seems off, because "*in*" along with "*armies*", means membership.  The act of issuing ushankas has nothing to do with army membership.

The correct use of "*in*" seems to be:

> Ushankas are issued in school.

This use of "*in*" makes sense, because "*in*" along with "*school*" means at what time the act of issuing ushankas takes place.

Does anyone agree with me that the sentence from the wikipedia is wrong?  Or, is my analysis wrong?

Comment: RE: _The act of issuing ushankas has nothing to do with army membership_ - On the contrary, this has **everything** to do with army membership. (Try getting issued an ushanka without enlisting in the army. Write us back when they give you one, comrade.)

Comment: I don't think "in" here implies they are *exclusively* given in this context. "In" here feels almost exactly equivalent to "to" (although that's partially because "armies" is ambiguous, it can either mean the soldiers or the administration).

Comment: I agree with your assessment, meatie. Issued **in** school makes sense, but the original sentence should either be "issued **by** Warsaw Pact armies" or "issued **to** Warsaw Pact soldiers".

Comment: Anything which is confined to an organization can be said to occur within the organization. Using in as a shortened form of within seems perfectly reasonable. And since "issuing" an object implies that the item will be used exclusively by a member of the organization, issuing has everything to do with membership. For instance, if a unit provided warm clothing, like a ushanka, to victims of a disaster, the ushankas would be given or donated or provided, not issued.

Comment: @BlueDot - _Issued **in**_ works just fine in the sentence. (That part of the sentence essentially means, "In all Warsaw pact armies, ushankas are issued.")

Answer (score 2):

You are overthinking this preposition *in* in the sentence. Let's rephrase it to a simple sentence removing the [absolute construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction):

> The ushanka is issued for all (the) soldiers (to wear in Winter) in all Warsaw Pact
>   armies.

You can see there are many unnecessary (redundant) words elided to make the sentence concise. The soldiers belong to all Warsaw Pact armies. Soldiers wear the ushanka in Winter. The reason *all (the) soldiers* is omitted is there is no reason to write it because the noun *army* implies that it includes soldiers. An army can't exist without soldiers.

Let's compare it with your sentence that has *school*:

> Ushankas are issued for all (the) students in school to wear in Winter.

You will see there is no difference between the two sentences. **Conciseness** is very important in an article.